# Ensuring Rows Add up to 100 but No Row is Less than 10 Algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix that I would like to ensure each row adds up to 100 but also ensure the minimum value of any row entry is an arbitrary number like 10.  Below is an example matrix:

```
matrixval=matrix(c(96,1,3,47,47,6,20,5,75),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=T)
```

Ideal result:

```
matrixval=matrix(c(80,10,10,45,45,10,18.947,10,71.053),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=T)
```

So all rows have a total value of 100, the minimum value is 10, and the amount taken away from the other rows is proportional to their values (see below for example calculation).

The last row was 20,5,75 so we need to take 5 away from 20 and 75, so we take 5/(20+75) * 75 = 3.947 away from 75 and 5/(20+75) * 20 = 1.053 away from 20 to get the final result.

Comment: Questions asking about how to code / manipulate data in R are off topic here. This will be on topic on [SO], so if you wait, we will try to migrate it there.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried?